# Merged linked lists

Tags: c

I am trying to create a linked list connected to other lists. The Main list will have index numbers and the sub lists will carry the data.

I have tried connecting a new node to the nodes of the main linked list but i am not sure if what i have done is correct. I am getting these errors during compilation :-

> 34:40: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>
> ```
>                       temp1->chain = temp2;
>                                     ^
> ```
>
> 39:40: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>
> ```
>                             tempT2 = temp1;
>                                     ^
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node1
{
    int Numbering1;
    int SizeOfList;
    struct node1* link1;
    struct node1* chain;
};
struct node2
{
    int Numbering2;
    int InList;
    struct node2* link2;
};
struct node1* root = NULL;
void ListLink(int *count)
{
    struct node1* temp1;
    struct node2* temp2;
    temp1 = (struct node1*)malloc(sizeof(struct node1));
    temp2 = (struct node2*)malloc(sizeof(struct node2));
    temp1->link1 = NULL;
    temp1->chain = NULL;
    temp2->link2 = NULL;
    temp1->Numbering1 = *count;
    *count++;
    scanf("%d",&temp1->SizeOfList);
    for(int i=0;i < temp1->SizeOfList; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&temp2->InList);
        if(temp1->chain == NULL)
        {
            temp1->chain = temp2;
        }
        else
        {
            struct node2* tempT2;
            tempT2 = temp1;
            while(tempT2->link2 != NULL)
            {
                tempT2 = tempT2->link2;
            }
            tempT2->link2 = temp2;
        }
    }
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = temp1;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node1* tempT1;
        tempT1 = root;
        while(tempT1->link1 != NULL);
        {
            tempT1 = tempT1->link1;
        }
        tempT1->link1 = temp1;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int index,query;
    scanf("%d%d",&index,&query);
    int OutList[index];
    int count = 0;
    ListLink(&count);
    return 0;
}
```

> I would like to know if I have made any mistakes in the program or if there are any better ways to do what i am trying to do.
>
> Is there a way to typecast and remove that incompatible pointer type error

Comment: Great that you paid attention to the warnings. They are a clear sign of "something is really wrong".

Comment: you have two different node types -- those errors are because you are assigning a pointer of one type to a pointer of the other type.

Comment: Notice that `chain` is a `struct node1 pointer` but `temp2` is a `struct node2 pointer` So you assing one pointer type to another pointer type. That is a no-go

Comment: ... and for `tempT2 = temp1` it is just the other way around.

Comment: OT: Do not - like in never ever - use a global variable for `root`.

Comment: @Aru Viser It is unclear what you are trying to do. For example this declaration in main int OutList[index]; is not used. You should split the function void ListLink(int *count) into several functions.

Comment: @Aru Viser The presented program does not make any sense.:)

Comment: i have yet to finish the program hence the OutList[index]. it isn't user friendly. it's just rough image of what i want.

Comment: i just wanted to know if what i am doing has faults and if those faults can be dealt with by making some changes or do i need to make a completely new code

Comment: @AruViser Could you explain _exactly_ what you want `ListLink` to do, because at the moment it is doing so many bogus things, it is hard to work out what you actually want.

Comment: Most of your difficulties are coming from the fact that you are using nondescriptive names. Why does `node1` carry the size of the list? Why does `ListLink` read from the keyboard? Rename `temp1` and `temp2` to things that are more meaningful and read your code aloud. Things will make more sense.

Comment: i will see what i can do to simplify the question.

Comment: @Aru Viser And I do not see a function that merges two linked lists. Such a function shall have at least two parameters that correspond to the first linked list and the second linked list. Where is there such a function?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do. The warnings (which you should treat as errors) are because you assing `struct node1` pointers to `struct node2`pointers (and vice versa).

My guess is that `chain` is of wrong type. Change it like:

```
struct node1* chain; --> struct node2* chain;
                                    ^
                                    note
```

Besides that - this line:

```
*count++;
```

is not doing what you expect - change it like:

```
*count++; --> (*count)++;
```

And here:

```
while(tempT1->link1 != NULL);
                            ^
                            Sure you want this ; ?
                            It looks wrong... 
                            I guess you need to delete the ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first warning, temp1->chain = temp2;, chain is a pointer of type "struct node1", and you are trying to assign temp2, its a pointer of type "struct node2". They are not compatible. 
viceversa in the second warning.
you need to explicitly typecast when you assign to different datatypes. However in this case its not recommended as there will be possible truncation of data.